# Cloudwatch insight grok extract json as field

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, grok, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am trying to extra a json field which can be either null or array.

example logs is;

```
04 Jun 2020 09:48:00,741 [32m[INFO] [m 4277a4fa-13fe-49f9-8348-9c515c988481  Class1: Method1: {"property1":"property1Value","property2":["string1", "string2"] , "property3": "property3Value"  }
04 Jun 2020 09:48:00,741 [32m[INFO] [m 4277a4fa-13fe-49f9-8348-9c515c988481  Class1: Method1: {"property1":"property1Value","property2":null , "property3": "property3Value"  }
```

Currently I am able to write a grok pattern which can either extract if property 2 is array

```
| parse "*property2*]*" as blah1, property2, blah2
```

Is there a way I can extract out null also here ?

Os is there a way to just convert @message to json object ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(?:case1|case2)` for case1 or case2.
For your example: `"property2":(?:null|\[(?<property2>.*?)])`

This gives:

for input `"property2":["string1", "string2"]` (your first log line):
`"property2": [[ ""string1", "string2"" ]]`

for input `"property2":null` (your second log line):
`"property2": [[ null ]]`

You can test it at http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/